# ckeditor throwing error in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ckeditor` for editing the content, I injected the module and also linked all files which are required by `ckeditor`, but it's throwing `error` like `TypeError: this[a] is undefined`, I am new in Angular, I didn't get any proper solution from myself.

Can anybody help me why I am getting this `error`?

Here is my code stuff

```
app.controller('editAboutUsCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.editorOptions = {
                language: 'eu'
               // uiColor: '#000000'
            };
            $scope.$on("ckeditor.ready", function( event ) {
                $scope.isReady = true;
            });
});
```

And here is my `HTML`

```
<div ng-controller="editAboutUsCtrl">
    <div ng-cloak ng-hide="isReady" class="highlight">
          Initialising ...
      </div>

      <div ng-cloak ng-show="isReady">
         <textarea ckeditor="editorOptions" name="editor" ng-model="aboutUsContent"></textarea>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me too. I think, it's a compression error.

Comment: Did you get any alternate to resolve it?

Comment: where did you inject the module? and are you talking about the ckeditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things about Angularjs

Refer to the style guide you like, however here is one if you do not follow one.

[A style guide link](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide)

Your controller name would become EditAboutUsCtrl.

I don't think you need the ng-cloak. That directive just hides the element until it has all its information then uncloaks. In your case you are using ng-hide and ng-show.

Your ng-model should be an object of some type, not a primative ex.
primative: "hello ckEditor"
object: var aboutUsContent = {};

If you need the name parameter, just know that this is used with a form name ex.

Then you can call $scope.myForm.editor.$valid?

Back to your question. The examples that I found online use a directive. You did not include an example in your code, but I will assume that ckeditor="editorOptions" is your directive.

So make sure it follows this example.

[example link to ckeditor with angularjs](http://sysmagazine.com/posts/200058/)

There are two jsfiddle examples at the end of the post. Here is the link to the one that seamed quite simple and perhaps you could use right away.

[try this](http://jsfiddle.net/fvApg/1/)

```
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h3>CKEditor 4.2:</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="editor in ckEditors">
    <textarea data-ng-model="editor.value" data-ck-editor></textarea>
    <br />
  </div>
  <button ng-click="addEditor()">New Editor</button>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

        var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

        ck.on('pasteState', function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
            });
        });

        ngModel.$render = function (value) {
            ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
        };
    }
  };
}])

function myCtrl($scope){
  $scope.ckEditors = [];
  $scope.addEditor = function(){
    var rand = ""+(Math.random() * 10000);
    $scope.ckEditors.push({value:rand});
  }
}
```